# How to add cellspacing="0" if it's not available for any `<table>` using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

How to add `cellspacing="0"` if it's not available for any `<table>` using jquery?

and if it's available and it has any other value than `="0"` then want to convert it to ="0"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('table').attr("cellspacing", 0);
```

Will change every table's cellspacing attribute to 0, whether it was previously defined or not.

Starting HTML:

```
<table> ... </table>
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"> ... </table>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0"> ... </table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"> ... </table>
```

Comment: and will it add `cellspacing="0"` to `table` if it's not available?

Comment: Seems exactly correct. The question is weirdly asked (sorry MGS), but basically the OP wants `cellspacing="0"` on all tables, and this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table id="table_id" cellspacing="0px">
 .................
```

Try:

```
if ($('#table_id').attr('cellspacing')) // does attribute exit
{
  if ('0px' != $('#table_id').attr('cellspacing'))
  {
    $('#table_id').attr('cellspacing', '0px') // make its value 0
  }
}
else // attribute does not exist
{
  $('#table_id').attr('cellspacing', '10px') // add
}
```

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: It is not wrong, try that out if you know. `cellspacing = '0px'`, it will come out to be `0px` if you set it to `cellspacing = '0'`, it will come out to be `0` string not number still.

Comment: @sAc - OK I thought we don't need measurement unit for `0` in html.

Comment: "0" is the same as "0px" (and "0em" and "0pt" and ...) In CSS, the units are not *required* when specifying a value of "0", but you can put them in if you like.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You should add further details in question so that the answer you like is provided. Always provide complete details in your questions please. And replacting units should not be a problem.

Comment: @Dean actually <code>em</code>'s won't work because this isn't a CSS value, but rather and HTML attribute. So <code>"10"</code>, <code>"10px"</code> and <code>"10pt"</code> are all the same... I think only "10" is valid however and will get you the most consitent results.
The CSS equivalent is <code>border-spacing:10px</code> and should be included in something like a reset.css which is generally used to normalize display across browsers.